I need to add my user to docker group each time I open console, how to solve this issue?
I am using Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS.
I need to add my user to docker group each time I open console to run a docker container, how to solve this issue?
I follow the same steps below whether installed Docker from Snap Store or from APT.
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp docker
docker run hello-world

Note: the system group "docker" already exists so I didn't need to create it again.

If you log out of your desktop session and log in again, it should reload the group list.  This isn't really specific to programming, and another site like [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] might be more appropriate (and probably has an answer already).

I really need to close session and start a new session to persist the group change.

Try this:
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER

logout or exit

then log in again and run groups in your terminal to see if any change has been effected.
You can also try:
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
newgrp -- docker
groups
docker run hello-world

